# Multiprocessing pool in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I had a scripts working in Python 2 and I am trying to make it work in Python 3.

One thing I stumbled upon and have no idea about how to solve is the fact that the get() method in the class Applyresult() seems to throw now:

In Pycharm the Traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 3.4.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1733, in <module>
    debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 3.4.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1226, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 3.4.1\helpers\pydev\_pydev_execfile.py", line 38, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc) #execute the script
  File "D:/SRC/CDR/trunk/RegressionTests/ExeTests/pyQCDReg_Launcher.py", line 125, in <module>
    result_list = ar.get()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 564, in get
    raise self._value
TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

The line offending is in pool.py:

```
def get(self, timeout=None):
    self.wait(timeout)
    if not self.ready():
        raise TimeoutError
    if self._success:
        return self._value
    else:
        raise self._value    // This is the line raising the exception
```

It is called from the following line in my script:

```
pool = Pool(processes=8)
ar = pool.map_async(run_regtest, command_list)
pool.close()
start_time = time.time()
while True:
    elapsed = time.time() - start_time
    if (ar.ready()): break
    remaining = ar._number_left
    print("Elapsed,", elapsed, ", Waiting for", remaining, "tasks to complete...")
    time.sleep(30)

pool.join()
ar.wait()
print("finished")
result_list = ar.get() // This is the offending line causing the exception
```

This script was working in Python 2 and I cannot understand why it would not be working in Python 3. Does anyone have an idea why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [multiprocessing documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult.get):

> get([timeout])
>
> ```
> Return the result when it arrives. If timeout is not None and
> the result does not arrive within timeout seconds then
> multiprocessing.TimeoutError is raised. If the remote call
> raised an exception then that exception will be reraised by
> get().
> ```

It seems likely to me that your exception comes from `run_regtest`.

The exception you are getting is pretty common when you switch from Python 2 to Python 3. Many functions in the standard library (and other libraries) that used to return `string`s now return `bytes`. A `bytes` object [can be converted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-and-bytearray-operations) to a string using `b.decode('utf-8')`, for example, you only need to know the encoding.

Comment: Yep, the actual error is in `run_regtest`. Looks like the changes to unicode handling in Python 3 have broken that function.

Comment: You were correct, I was using a reg exp on the non-regresssion test output which was in bytes before to decode it.